# Linq output changes

Tags: c#, sql, linq

So I have a pretty simple SQL call

```
SELECT count(col1) as count, sum(col2) as charges, col3, col4 
FROM table GROUP BY col3, col4
```

When I do the above call I get 4,961 rows returned.

When I run the results through the following linq statement it returns the data in a different order every single time it runs.

I guess what my disconnect here is, is why do I get different results? Shouldn't the below linq block parse the data the same no matter what order it's in?

```
IEnumerable<Chart.Point> recs = from a in
   (from r in cache.Data
      where ids.Contains(r[idColName].ToString())
         group r by r[ranColName].ToString() into g
            select new Chart.Point { Key = g.Key, Value = g.Sum(x => 
                 Convert.ToInt64(x[countCol])) }).Take(numberOfColumns)
     orderby a.Value descending, a.Key
     select a;
```

Comment: So your question is why the database returns its data in an arbitrary and unspecified order when you have not specified a desired order?

Comment: No I understand that. The question is why does the linq produce different results every time when its obviously ordering

Comment: Does the ordering become consistent if you remove the `Take` clause? The fact that you are `Take`-ing the top results from an un-ordered source sequence is suspicious.

Comment: @SteveRuble Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @SteveRuble so I can't confirm this without fully testing all the different code paths but it appears this does work. Can you post this as an answer and explain why it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's split the query to make things a little clearer:

```
var points = 
  from r in cache.Data                               
  where ids.Contains(r[idColName].ToString())       
  group r by r[ranColName].ToString() into g        
  select new Chart.Point {                          
   Key = g.Key,                                     
   Value = g.Sum(x => Convert.ToInt64(x[countCol])) 
  };

var topPoints = points.Take(numberOfColumns);

var orderedPoints = from a in topPoints
                    orderby a.Value descending, a.Key
                    select a;
```

The `cache.Data` property has an arbitrary order, because it's populated from a SQL query which doesn't specify ordering. This means that `topPoints` may end up with a different set of points each time. As a result, the ordering will appear to be different on different runs (but in reality it is *the points being ordered* which is different, not really *the ordering of the points*).

You should be able to get a consistent, ordered, and limited sequence of points by moving the `Take` operation after the ordering operation, so that the same points will always be at the top before the limit is applied.

Comment: Gorgeous example. I am trying it now. Thank you